# webpack.DefinePlugin and jshint "is not defined"

Tags: jshint, webpack

I am using `webpack.DefinePlugin` to inject global constants as part of my build pipeline. jshint however complains that the constant "is not defined".

From my webpack.config.js:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __ALEX__: JSON.stringify('alex.com')
    }),
```

leads to:

```
WARNING in ./src/Main.js
jshint results in errors
  '__ALEX__' is not defined. @ line 12 char 30
      lock: new Thing(__ALEX__)
```

What is the correct way to have jshint look at the code after the constants are injected?

Comment: Can you try moving jshint as a postLoader?

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the `eslint-loader`...

Comment: Do you specifically not want to add `"globals": {"__ALEX__": true}` to your .jshintrc/.eslintrc?

Comment: Hello Alex, did you manage to get this working right? I'm having the problem with `eslint-loader` on my project, but on another it seems to work. So I'm investigating...

Comment: To get around this for typescript, I created a webpack.config.d.ts with `declare const __ALEX__;`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "globals": {
        "__ALEX__": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
    }
}
```

Without adding the `parser` and `parsterOptions` fields, I get weird pre ECMA Script 16 errors.